# How can i edit the x1 y1 x2 y2 of javascript image object with an src(cropping)

Tags: javascript

I'm basically trying to split an image(spritesheet) into a bunch of frames. To do this, I want to use the original image, then chose the x1, x2, y1, and y2 of the original image to get each frame. Is this possible to do in plain javascript using the image object?

In pseudo code:

```
const frame1 = new Image();
frame1.src = path;
frame1.x1 = 0;
frame1.y1 = 0;
frame1.x2 = 20;
frame1.y2 = 20;
const frame2 = new Image();
frame2.src = path;
frame2.x1 = 20;
frame2.y1 = 0;
frame2.x2 = 40;
frame2.y2 = 20;
```

Comment: I think this tutorial will be helpfull: https://yellowpencil.com/blog/cropping-images-with-javascript/ Next time please take a moment to search with Google as Stack Overflow is not the place to request a tutorial on how to do something. Basicly, if your question starts with _"How do I..."_, SO is wrong place to ask. If it starts with _"I've tried ... it didn't work, what went wrong?"_, SO is the place to be.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I did browse quite a bit, but most answers involved the canvas, or just didn't work in my situation. I'll check this out

Comment: Well obviously you need to load the image somewhere before you'll be able to edit it. I mean, if you want to do something and you are presented with the tool needed for that, you're making it pretty impossible if you don't want to use that tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a function called `createImageBitmap()` that easily crops the image object without using the canvas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a `<canvas>` - you don't need to add it to the page, you just need to use it in JavaScript for the image transformation / export to data URL abilities.

Essentially:

- Make a canvas which is the width and height of the cropped image (e.g. `x2-x1` and `y2-y1`)
- Place the image `-x1` and `-y1` pixels off of the canvas to crop to that point
- The canvas will now only contain the parts of the image that fall within it
- We get the contents of the canvas using `toDataURL`, and then create a new `Image` object with that as the `src` attribute.

Here's the code:

```
function crop(img, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let cv = document.createElement("canvas");
    cv.width = x2 - x1; //Width of cropped image
    cv.height = y2 - y1; //Height of cropped image
    let ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, -x1, -y1); //Starting x / y for cropping
    let result = new Image();
    result.src = cv.toDataURL(); //The cropped image is whatever is on the canvas
    return result;
}
```